# How can I update my remote "origin/master" with my local history

Tags: git, bitbucket, phpstorm, branch

Context:

No one else has committed.

I created a branch to revert back at one point, and then continued making edits.
My local Master and Local history are currently the "truth" of what I want live and remembered in the repo.

However when I try to push it gets rejected from the remote Origin/Master and then I try to pull, it also fails (see screenshot).

I really want to preserve my local history and have it saved remotely, that's all.

Thanks for shining some light!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to preserve the following commits that are on the `remote/master`:

```
* Lots of search..
* Replace all..
* Replace all..
* Committing additional ..
* Committing all files..
* Fixes to try to restore site
```

If the answer is NO and all those commits should be not preserved, then simply do:

```
git checkout master // To make sure you are on the local master branch
git push -f // Force push your local master to remote/master
```

If however the answer is YES and all those commits should be preserved, then you'll first need to `rebase` your `local master` onto the `remote/master` as shown below:

#### If the commits to be preserved on `remote/master` should come at last:

```
git checkout origin/master // To make sure you are on the remote/master branch
git rebase master // we rebase remote/master to local master
                  // At this point, you might have some conflicts so follow the
                  // guide the rebase offers to resolve them
git push -f       // Force pushing the remote/master
```

#### If the commits to be preserved on `remote/master` should come at starting:

```
git checkout master // To make sure you are on the local branch
git rebase origin/master // we rebase local master to remote master
                  // At this point, you might have some conflicts so follow the
                  // guide the rebase offers to resolve them
git push -f       // Force pushing the local master
```

Comment: Thank you so much! In the PHPStorm GUI, the Force Push option was disabled. When I tried `git push -f` the terminal said I set to set origin master as the upstream. So the final command that did the trick was:
`git push -f --set-upstream origin master`

Comment: Nice awesome its fixed now